# Discord.py Cogs take at most 2 arguments

Tags: discord, discord.py

When I tried adding a Cog for my bot it gives me a TypeError

> module() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)

```py
class Commands(commands.cog):
  def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client
    self.song_queue = {}

    self.setup()

  def setup(self):
    for guild in self.client.guilds():
      self.song_queue[guild.id] = []
```

I also set it up using

```py
async def setup():
  client.add_cog(Commands(client))

client.loop.create_task(setup())
```

Comment: If you're trying to add an extension, remove this line `client.loop.create_task(setup())` and make the setup function synchronous, discord.py automatically calls the setup function.

Comment: I removed it but it still says that the error is on the line where i defined the class

Comment: Also `commands.Cog` with capital C

Comment: zthe bot got online but all the commands in the class dont show up

Comment: `guilds` is a list, you can't call it, and `self.client.guilds` will always be empty, you'll need to find another way to have a setup function when the bot is "ready"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`guilds` is a list, you can't call it, and `self.client.guilds` will always be empty, you'll need to find another way to have a setup function when the bot is "ready" –
Taku